# VBA to parse and retrieve data from HTML to Excel

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a macro in VBA to transfer data from a website to a spreadsheet.  My problem is that my code does not yield any results for href, innertext, etc.  Can you help advise where my code is wrong?

Here is a sample of the html--I am trying to retrieve the lot number 41151 and the description.

```
<tr class=''>
    <td class='lot_column'>
        <div class='lot_number'>
            <span class='lot_digits'>41151</span>
            <br />
            <a href='property_information.pl?lot=41151' class='sd_button blue'><span>View Data</span></a>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class='short_desc'>Michael L. Hanisko, A/I/F for Shirley Isackson -     Winterfield Richfield Unit and Grout Unit (Producing MI/RI) - Clare and Gladwin Counties, Michigan</div>
        <div class='headline'>7 Mo. Av. Cash Flow $15/mo</div>
        <div class='message'></div>
    </td>
    <td class='high_bid'>
        <div class='high_bid'>$810</div>
        <div class='reserve_status'>No&nbsp;Reserve</div>
    </td>
    <td class='lot_close'>
        <span class='closing_date'>8/29/2017 1:35 PM</span>
        <br />
        <a href='bidder_bid.pl?lot=41151' class='sd_button red'><span>Make Bid</span </a>
    </td>
```

Here is a segment of my code:

```
Set Lot_Data = EnergyNet.getElementsByClassName("lot_digits")
For Each elem In Lot_Data
    Set Link = elem.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)
    i = i + 1
    'Copy Data to Excel
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B" & i) = Link.href
    Range("C" & i) = Link.innerText
    Range("D" & i) = Link.ID
Next
```

Any idea where I went wrong?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: put a breakpoint at the `for each ....` line. then when the code stops there, examine the `Lot_Data` object using the _Watch window_  .... i think that the 41151 is in `Lot_Data.innertext` .... the rest of the data is in one of the _siblings_ ..... `<span class='lot_digits'>41151</span>` does not have any _children_

Comment: if you indent the html code properly, then you may see how the elements relate to each other

Comment: Thanks @jsotola, that's really helpful.  It looks like you are right, "<span class='lot_digits'>41151</span>" does not have any children.  Without knowing the lot number (e.g. 41151), how can I extract this number and it's sibling data into the spreadsheet?  Thanks again.

Comment: it is in the `elem.parent.parent.sibling`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get

```
<span class='lot_digits'>41151</span>
```

then from this you want to get an element with tag name of "**tr**" but in the **span**, with the **lot_digits** class there isn't any element with **tr** as tag name so the **Link** variable will be empty.

For the 41151 element you have to

```
Set Lot_Data = EnergyNet.getElementsByClassName("lot_digits")
```

then

```
Lot_Data(0).innerText will contain 41151
```

For the description, simply

```
Set descriptionElements = EnergyNet.getElementsByClassName("short_desc")
```

and

```
descriptionElements(0).innerText
```

will contain the description

Comment: Thanks for your help exSnake.  I tried to instead get the "lot_digits" class data from the tag "span," but the loop is still not returning any data (href, innertext, class, etc.) to the spreadsheet.  How would you change the code to fix this?  I'm pretty new to using html and VBA web tools.  Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer